# Hartshorne IV Remark 4.10.9 a morphism to Jacobian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As in the title, in Hartshorne's algebraic geometry chapter IV Remark 4.10.9, $X$ is a curve over $k$ and $J$ is the Jacobian variety of $X$ of $X$. There he defines a morphism $X^n \rightarrow J$ by "$(P_1, \cdots, P_n) \mapsto \mathcal{L}(P_1+\cdots+P_n - nP_0)$."

According to the definition of the Jacobian variety by the universal property, this is equivalent to give an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{M}$ on $X \times X^n$ such that for $(P_1, \cdots, P_n) \in X^n, \ \mathcal{M}_{(P_1, \cdots, P_n)} \simeq \mathcal{L}(P_1+\cdots+P_n - nP_0).$

But how does one know that there is such an invertible sheaf?

Answer (score 2):

Define $p\colon X\times X^n\to X$ by
$$
p(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)=x
$$
and $q_{01},\dots,q_{0n}\colon X\times X^n\to X\times X$ by
$$
q_{0i}(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)=(x,y_i).
$$
Let $\Delta$ denote the diagonal divisor of $X\times X$.
Then $\mathcal{L}(\Delta)$ is a line bundle on $X\times X$ whose restriction to $X\times \{P\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}(P)$.
Consider the line bundle
$$
\mathcal{M}:=q_{01}^*\mathcal{L}(\Delta)\otimes\dots\otimes q_{0n}^*\mathcal{L}(\Delta)\otimes p^*\mathcal{L}(P_0)^{\otimes -n}.
$$
on $X\times X^n$.
Then the restriction of $\mathcal{M}$ to $X\times \{(P_1,\dots,P_n)\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}(P_1+\dots+P_n-nP_0)$.